# Why have so few people received a second dose of the vaccine COVID-19 in India?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

From https://www.google.com/search?q=india+covid+cases&oq=india+covid+cases:

[image]

Why have so few people received a second dose of the vaccine COVID-19 in India?

I've searched for "india second dose vaccine" without any success.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the graph carefully. In the second week of March less than half of 50M have been vaccinated. It is April's third week and if you look carefully almost as many people who had to take a second jab seem to have taken it. Majority of first shots have been taken in the end of March so we need to check the data at the end of April i.e after a month because that is the recommended gap between the two shots. Moreover the vaccine is said to have been made free of cost at government hospitals. Dr.Reddy's a reputed pharma company reported that SputnikV shall be arriving very soon into India. The graph should go up soon.

There were some issues though:

1. The only two vaccines that had been granted emergency use authorization by the [Central Drugs Standard Control Organization](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mohfw.gov.in/pdf/FAQsforHCWs%26FLWs.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiM6L6BnpHwAhWg7XMBHW2iBMcQFjAOegQIGBAC&usg=AOvVaw0-IfYugOSN6waixYUF7C3O&cshid=1619073334574) (CDSCO) in India are Covishield® (AstraZeneca's vaccine manufactured by Serum Institute of India) and Covaxin® (manufactured by Bharat Biotech Limited). [Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_vaccination_in_India) you can read about the latest developments.
2. Both these vaccines were not trusted by the public. Blood clotting side effect of Astra-Zeneca and [because Covaxin wasn't put through the final trial phase before allowing it's use](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2021-01-14/india-begins-covid-19-vaccinations-amid-doubts-over-drug?_amp=true). One of the very esteemed [scientists](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/health/i-would-not-take-the-vaccine-without-efficacy-data-gagandeep-kang/article33527186.ece/amp/) also denied taking the Covaxin because of the lack of efficacy data.
   Bharat Biotech recently provided efficacy data and the public might've started trusting it since then and hence the recent surge in first vaccine shots.
3. It was recently [reported](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ndtv.com/india-news/coronavirus-huge-vaccine-wastage-by-states-till-april-11-most-in-tamil-nadu-rti-shows-2417643%3famp=1&akamai-rum=off) that a huge number of COVID vaccines were wasted. Some news articles like [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.livemint.com/news/india/why-6-5-of-coronavirus-vaccine-doses-in-india-are-going-to-waste/amp-11615993563664.html) explain why this is happening.